# Allowing stack to Create multiple ecr images

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a case where single Dockerfile is able to build 2 of my projects that are sharing a directory

```
cdk_project
src
  \Project1
  \Project2
  \ProjectShared
  \Dockerfile
```

using the CDK i am trying to create 2 separate services in the stack

```
const web_app_image_asset = new DockerImageAsset(this, 'webapp', {

      directory: "../src",
      buildArgs: {
        "PROJECT_DIR": "webapp"
      }
    });

const api_image_asset = new DockerImageAsset(this, 'api', {
      directory: "../src",
      buildArgs: {
        "PROJECT_DIR": "api",
      }
    });

const web_service = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
      cluster,
      "web-Service",
      {
        cluster,
        taskImageOptions: {
          image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(web_app_image_asset .repository),
        },
      }
    );

const api_service = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
      cluster,
      "api-Service",
      {
        cluster,
        taskImageOptions: {
          image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(api_image_asset.repository),
        },
      }
    );
```

problem though is that there is only a single image being created and i am expecting that once the buildArg is different it would allow docker to build a second image but it is not.

Dockerfile

```
FROM abiosoft/caddy:php
ARG PROJECT_DIR=webapp

ADD PROJECT_SHARED /PROJECT_SHARED
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ARG PROJECT_DIR
COPY $PROJECT_DIR  .
COPY ./Caddyfile /etc/Caddyfile
RUN composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using targets in your Dockerfile. 
Recently, a release added the possibility to specify a target in your build (https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/4185)

Then your Dockerfile could look something like this:

```
FROM abiosoft/caddy:php as project_base

ADD PROJECT_SHARED /PROJECT_SHARED
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

FROM project_base as project_webapp

ARG PROJECT_DIR=webapp
COPY $PROJECT_DIR  .
COPY ./Caddyfile /etc/Caddyfile
RUN composer install 

FROM project_base as project_api

ARG PROJECT_DIR=api
COPY $PROJECT_DIR  .
COPY ./Caddyfile /etc/Caddyfile
RUN composer install
```

Then your CDK code would be like this:

```
const apiImage = new DockerImageAsset(this, 'apiImage', {
      directory: '../src',
      target: 'api',
    });

const webappImage = new DockerImageAsset(this, 'webappImage', {
      directory: '../src',
      target: 'webapp',
    });
```